# getting error in exchanging the base address of 2d araay using a third variable

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Apppraently, what the programs attempt to do is interchanging the address stored in `names[3]` and `names[40]` using an auxiliary variable `t`. but I am getting error

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  char names[5][20] = {"rrr","kkkk","hddj","dhfjdj","jjdnfjd"};
  int i;
  char *t;
  t = names[3];
  names[3] = names[4];
  names[4] = t;
  for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", names[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you think you can assign string like this.?

Comment: This is not possible. An array is not a pointer, and you can't assign to an array either. You will need to copy the contents to an appropriately-sized temporary buffer instead. (BTW, had you thought about the problem beforehand, would you have realized that it didn't make sense.)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int main()
{
char names[5][20]={"rrr","kkkk","hddj","dhfjdj","jjdnfjd"};
int i;
char *t=malloc(20*sizeof(char));
strcpy(t,names[3]);
strcpy(names[3],names[4]);
strcpy(names[4],t);
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    printf("%s\n",names[i]);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Heya, don't forget to explain what you changed and why. There are heaps of newbies on Stack Overflow and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise. What may seem obvious to you might not be to them...

Answer (score 0):

you can try any one of this...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
 int main()
 {
 char names[5][20]={"rrr","kkkk","hddj","dhfjdj","jjdnfjd"};
 int i;


 char t[20];//or char *t=malloc(20*sizeof(char));

 strcpy(t,names[3]);
 strcpy(names[3],names[4]);
 strcpy(names[4],t);

 for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
 printf("%s\n",names[i]);
 }

 return 0;
}
```